# Copy line number in text file c#

Tags: c#, text-files

I have 2 files file A and file B how need to copy line 30 on file A and paste it over the top of line 30 in file B can I do this in C#?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is possible, but i'd like to see what you have tried so far before giving you some suggestions.

Comment: Please make more of an effort.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a *very* simple way, assuming file B is small enough to read into memory:

```
string lineFromA = File.ReadLines("fileA.txt").Skip(29).First();
string[] linesFromB = File.ReadAllLines("fileB.txt");
linesFromB[29] = lineFromA;
File.WriteAllLines("fileC.txt", linesFromB);
```

This assumes you're using .NET 4, with its lazy [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) method. If you're not, the simplest approach would be to read *both* files into memory completely, using [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines) twice:

```
string[] linesFromA = File.ReadAllLines("fileA.txt");
string[] linesFromB = File.ReadAllLines("fileB.txt");
linesFromB[29] = linesFromA[29];
File.WriteAllLines("fileC.txt", linesFromB);
```

There are definitely more *efficient* approaches, but I'd go with the above unless I had any reason to need a more efficient one.

Comment: I would have preferred a `linesFromB[29] = linesFromA[29]` approach, but all the same ;p

Comment: @leppie: I figured it's still pretty simple this way, and at least now we can cope with a huge file A, even if file B still need to be small. Will include the other solution too...

Answer (score 0):

If you use a streamwriter for the writing side you get a routine that does not use a lot of memory and can also be used for larger files.

```
        string lineFromA = File.ReadLines("fileA.txt").Skip(29).First();
        using (var fileC = File.AppendText("fileC.txt"))
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var lineFromB in File.ReadLines("fileB.txt"))
            {
                i++;
                fileC.WriteLine(i != 30 ? lineFromB : lineFromA);
            }
        }
```